# Can a Windsor WCF client be used in a service configured as singleton?

Tags: c#, wcf, castle-windsor

Castle Windsor's WCF facility allows for easy configuration of WCF clients using the `.AsWcfClient(...)` extension method during configuration. However, what happens when the channel faults? Can I depend on the interface from a service configured with singleton lifestyle? If not, what would be the best way to make use of the WCF client facility in conjunction with singleton services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windsor gives you the ability to refresh faulted channels. https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/wcf-facility-refresh-channel-policy.md